# ASP.Net MVC Controller and View interaction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I created a sample `MVC application` using following Template.

> ASP.NET MVC2 Empty Web Application

Then a added a `Controller` with the name of `First` and a right clicked the `ActionResult` to add a `View`.

I typed `http://localhost:49565/First` in my Browser.

**Query**

How is the controller internally getting to know that a specific page will be displayed when we will type `http://localhost:49565/First` ?

Moreover, If I add multiple Views for a `Controller`. How will the system decide which one will be displayed on Priority ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question about MVC is on the very, very  basic elements of the framework. I would suggest you look at one of the many tutorials for beginners on the web before you post questions here. e.g: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: Welcome to my first question in SO. This is a very specific question after reading MVC tutorials. Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is invoked by the MVC framework, which uses the routes defined in Global.asax.cs to determine which controller and action to invoke. There is a default route that looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

When the application receives a request is will try to parse the URL to the format of the routes. If the request is made to `http://localhost:49565/`, it will use the default values which goes to the `Index` action in the controller named `HomeController`. When you have created the new controller, `FirstController`, and call `http://localhost:49565/First`, it uses the `FirstController` instead of the `HomeController` since it has been provided (but still to the `Index` action).

Further, when an action is being invoked and there is no view defined explicitly, it will look for a view named the same as the invoked action. In your case it would be `~/Views/First/Index.aspx`.

**EDIT**

If you want to use another view you can specify it in the return statement

```
return View("OtherView");
```

and it will use `~/Views/First/OtherView.aspx` instead.

Comment: I have two Views `1. Index.aspx and View1.aspx` Whenever I type `http://localhost:49565/First` in my Browser, How can I invoke `View1.aspx`. Right now it is always showing `Index.aspx` page.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. I could not upvote due to less reputations.:)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/an-introduction-to-asp.net-mvc-extensibility/) blog posts give u the idea of how it is done